# Unable to connect Python to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, database, python-requests

I'm using pycharm 2017 and SQL Server 2019 and my problem is I use this code:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='sa', password='pooria1376',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='pooriadb')
cnx.close()
```

I see this error:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/LA/PycharmProjects/untitled/main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 509, in open_connection
    self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LA/PycharmProjects/untitled/main", line 5, in <module>
    database='pooriadb')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 512, in open_connection
    errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Also I disabled firewall , "sa" is default username of SQL Server and I'm sure my password is true (because I login with this information). Anyone can please help me?

Comment: Kindly run the following command and provide the respective output `Select user from mysql.user;`

Comment: You said that "sa" is the default username but your code is using "admin" as username

Comment: @ozgursar yea i created full grant username named "admin" but even with sa or admin it doesn't work.

Comment: @SamakshGupta maybe i'm very new to this topic and i need to be guided more clearly, i copied your code into SSMS and terminal gave me this:
```Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.```

Comment: You're using a MySQL driver to attempt to connect to SQL Server - they are completely different database engines... it will never work. You need the correct driver.

Comment: @DaleK so what should i do now?

Comment: Use the correct driver.

Comment: @DaleK i downloaded mysql installer and i installed this, it seemed that using sql_server_2019_enterprise was wrong. it took 20 days of my time. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

try checking if the mysql service is running on the localhost